# Authentication web scraping issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I don't know why I couldn't POST my session after I did all of this.

I tried to see if I miss any information from the form, like the hidden token but it seems like they didn't even have a form.

Could someone point me out a direction? Thank you so much in advance

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = myUserName
password = myPassword

scrape_url = 'https://ags.aspengrove.net/Property/PropertySummary.aspx?PropertyID=1366919'


login_url = 'https://ags.aspengrove.net/Library/Security/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fIndex.aspx'
login_info = {'ctl01$MainContent$tbxPerson': username,'ctl01$MainContent$tbxPassword': password}

#Start session.
session = requests.session()

#Login
r = session.post(url=login_url, data=login_info)

#Request page you want to scrape.
headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"
}

url = session.get(url=scrape_url,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

print(r.status_code)


for td in soup.findAll('td'):
  print('\n\n\n')
  print('text: ' + str(td.text))

session.close()
```

Comment: How come you don't have a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to start looking at a page like this is to simply make a POST request and see what it does. In Chrome, the POST data appears to be the following fields:

```
ctl01_ctlScriptManager_HiddenField: 
__EVENTTARGET: ctl01$MainContent$btnLogin
__EVENTARGUMENT: 
__VIEWSTATE__: RU7PS8MwGKVZQ91AcitebHPYYQOVzR842M2hFx2MKl5L2nztwtJEk9S5v17TMvHyvsd773u8n4CcBTjJ85VWzmhpM/hshYGNtu6BlbtnOOR5HOC0dHI2H6+ZUF0SlBuX210GDTQFmDUQPLqc3y9mi+ubu1sSh8noSRjrXnQtFMYVkxaS0wwqMEaoesNq4DGqiAc06DH0GPb8BAWkN2OURO/CikJCzb0VoxR5Ev2RYf9yDHcdAel+wjf4dvji0a809KBbQ6FhQlLGuQFrKVOcfjBr99pwWoDU+yvOjyuC/550AF7GvTAk3UkirUopyh0+N+Bao+ikcOqVfUG+6uSJ2wo7nS75Lw==
__VIEWSTATE: 
__EVENTVALIDATION: Z+yHsUlIzPcsXdpj1bBqQkEDPqzzZPfBKwo/SI3nW5r4vyVU240IulzvcQOvQ5FLpkCLPwPUhdDRs0dGzhW3VQyWQjAjktxQ6FbmHS6dY0bEhbG6hkPAIxF3rEfHyQpnmuCflUGUC0HWxtr8LNx1oiUzOSrdrMhLuCLvWi01mvoc7vnsES6K97wbg1AUfun/Z2062CHFXbUcQYyr1KBLwVs13Y6FWr+e3Ruyb5EaftqQOSbtSRg8ZP1zE1aj05qY4tWBlG7hCIfl00xq6n6Zv0q6p9WrbkPdUv6/Gw==
ctl01$TimeOffset: 
ctl01$MainContent$hidPassExpression: /^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%^*!_=?:|,()-]).*$/
ctl01$MainContent$hidPassLength: 8
ctl01$MainContent$hidPassCode: 
ctl01$MainContent$tbxPerson: abcdef@efghij.com
ctl01$MainContent$tbxPassword: a@@@@@@@@1
```

It's an ASP.net page so there's quite a bit to get. The proper thing to do is to look over the whole login page and match up the elements. The quick (but dirty) way to figure out what the fields look like is simply let bs4 grab all the input tags.

```
import bs4
import requests

headers = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"}

r = requests.get("https://ags.aspengrove.net/Library/Security/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fProperty%2fPropertySummary.aspx%3fPropertyID%3d1366919&PropertyID=1366919", headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
itags = soup.find_all(name="input")
for tag in itags:
    print(tag)
```

Result looks like

```
<input id="ctl01_ctlScriptManager_HiddenField" name="ctl01_ctlScriptManager_HiddenField" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input id="__EVENTTARGET" name="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input id="__EVENTARGUMENT" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input id="__VIEWSTATE__" name="__VIEWSTATE__" type="hidden" value="RU7PS8MwGKVZQ91AcitebHPYYQOVzR842M2hFx2MKl5L2nztwtJEk9S5v17TMvHyvsd773u8n4CcBTjJ85VWzmhpM/hshYGNtu6BlbtnOOR5HOC0dHI2H6+ZUF0SlBuX210GDTQFmDUQPLqc3y9mi+ubu1sSh8noSRjrXnQtFMYVkxaS0wwqMEaoesNq4DGqiAc06DH0GPb8BAWkN2OURO/CikJCzb0VoxR5Ev2RYf9yDHcdAel+wjf4dvji0a809KBbQ6FhQlLGuQFrKVOcfjBr99pwWoDU+yvOjyuC/550AF7GvTAk3UkirUopyh0+N+Bao+ikcOqVfUG+6uSJ2wo7nS75Lw=="/>
<input id="__VIEWSTATE" name="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input id="__EVENTVALIDATION" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" type="hidden" value="Nw7wmof2VXeD0/HsHnbqEV3JYs/jUm1FUFYbO2NxwJVUOXSdi+ulpjvZ501wLkSCJVkUlTOMNkaCw9d+fr74I9lkObY9N2zwbqbcEcac6af8hP5vblYExcMszLJNqOrAuNPqRUjsV91y5/PPekrgOuvM1O1ep5kvpzMfljrCLngSTNYbU9iEruOYL29RwQPz4+521uAjowigFf7fCEYTaqfuJZrML5WYNKW7eu7KxyxeEXpjG1K+Ufxxs7X1PTU3XoYw+qkUYp1RexvoCgdFlCkbZstCiOpU8PI5TA=="/>
<input id="ctl01_TimeOffset" name="ctl01$TimeOffset" type="hidden"/>
<input id="ctl01_MainContent_hidPassExpression" name="ctl01$MainContent$hidPassExpression" type="hidden" value="/^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%^*!_=?:|,()-]).*$/"/>
<input id="ctl01_MainContent_hidPassLength" name="ctl01$MainContent$hidPassLength" type="hidden" value="8"/>
<input id="ctl01_MainContent_hidPassCode" name="ctl01$MainContent$hidPassCode" type="hidden"/>
<input class="TextBox" id="ctl01_MainContent_tbxPerson" name="ctl01$MainContent$tbxPerson" size="50" type="text"/>
<input class="TextBox" id="ctl01_MainContent_tbxPassword" name="ctl01$MainContent$tbxPassword" size="30" type="password"/>
<input class="button" id="ctl01_MainContent_btnLogin" name="ctl01$MainContent$btnLogin" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value = 'Logging In';__doPostBack('ctl01$MainContent$btnLogin','')" type="button" value="Login"/>
<input id="ctl01_MainContent_chkRememberMe" name="ctl01$MainContent$chkRememberMe" type="checkbox"/>
```

You can grab all of the name fields by iterating through the list as well

```
for tag in itags:
    print(tag["name"])
```

The only value you don't have off the bat are the email/password and the __EVENTTARGET, which is just the name of the submit button input.

And from there you should be able to submit the proper POST data for the login.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try! And comment back to you.

Comment: I did it. Thank you so much. Learn something new everyday. : D

Comment: Glad you got it!